# Script requires old tensorflow, many GPUs. Where to run?

Tags: python, tensorflow, hpc

I'm trying to run a tutorial for this framework called Pocketflow (following the instructions [here](https://pocketflow.github.io/installation/)) which basically boils down to running a bash script with a parameter of a python script:

`./scripts/run_local.sh nets/resnet_at_cifar10_run.py`

Pocketflow requires Tensorflow version 1.10.0 and it needs to use idle GPUs. Therefore, I am thinking I should run it on a cluster (many GPUs) with a virtual environment (to specify the TF version). Is there a simpler way to go about this? The installation [page](https://pocketflow.github.io/installation/) outlines a "docker" method and a "seven" method, but I'm not familiar with those concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**TensorFlow Version**

From the [requirement.txt](https://github.com/Tencent/PocketFlow/blob/master/requirement.txt) file of PocketFlow, it seems requires at least 1.10.0, it would work fine with anything above (except some warnings and deprecated notices).

**Where to Run?**

You should already know it. If you have a GPU cluster, run it there. Otherwise, you can use free GPU options like [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/running-kaggle-kernels-with-a-gpu) and [Colab](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html): [Example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb). In Colab you can define which TensorFlow version to use, [official example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb). If you choose anyone between Kaggel and Colab, you may need to modify the original codes you have to use PocketFlow.

If you have your own GPU cluster and I assume you'll have Linux system installed. You have two option to choose from

**Use Python Virtual Environments**

1. Create it: `python3 -m venv pocketflow-env`
2. Activate it: `source pocketflow-env/bin/activate`
3. Install required packages with version: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**Use Docker**

1. Check if it's already installed by running `docker version` if returns appropriate messages, which means [default output](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/version/#default-output), then it means Docker is already installed. Otherwise, install Docker by following the official documentation: [Install Docker on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/).
   Then, you just need to run the next two commands as the [official documentation of PocketFlow](https://pocketflow.github.io/installation/#prepare-for-the-docker-mode) describes
2. `docker pull uber/horovod` it pulls [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/uber/horovod) from Dockerhub and stores in your system to use it for next command
3. `./scripts/run_docker.sh nets/resnet_at_cifar10_run.py`